# how get site conent using php

Tags: php, tags

For example my site is mysite.com. Here is source of this site:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>site</title>
//here is many javascript and css codes
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td><a href="somthing.html">Here is a text</td>
  <td><img src="image.gif" alt="this is image"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I using php get only text and image without all tags(javascript codes, links, tables and other)? 
I want get only "here is a text" and "image.gif".

Comment: I dont really understand what your asking?

Comment: @Sam i want get only text and image without tags

Comment: Apologies, obviously other people do :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP cURL if the file is on the internet else you can use the `file_get_contents()` function if the file on the local machine.

To get rid of the extra tags you can use the code:

```
$contents - file_get_contents('file.html');
$contents = strip_tags( $contents, '<img>' ); //other than <img> you can specify more tags also
```

Alternatively you can use the DOM approach also.